# Release resources from the threads

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

In my application (at my work), we maintain socket connection pool to handle the communication . There are a number of threads (number is large) which take an active connection from the pool, use it and close it. But the catch is that somewhere in between garbage collector is invoked to collect the references not in use.

Now, after the garbage collector is invoked I want to:

1. suspend all the threads which participate in the communication(please note that my threads run together with the GC -> I mean scheduling makes it possible)
2. release the socket connections from the thread (i.e.references to the socket connection) whose status may be somewhere in between or if that is practically not feasible then:
3. How to delay the invocation of GC after all the threads using the resources have finished. further in this case it may be required to determine whether the relevant threads have finished their job.

Comment: You don't get this kind of fine-grained interaction with the GC in Java.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Comment: gc needs to be tuned since the number of threads is large. Hence after the threads are done , there will be considerable memory footprint. there won't be any great benefit of running GC. Hence want to delay till all the relevant threads are finished or free the resources somehow

Comment: @MridulVishal you dont have any control as to when gc will run and there is no Observer pattern available in Java which will notify you of GC, it is just outside your control

Answer (score 2):

If you care when GC runs, then your application design is broken.

Fix your design.

Note: Although there are specifications for how the garbage collector should operate, it is not a *requirement* that JVM implementations even *have* a garbage collector!